# Determine Number of Reduce in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

In Hadoop, the number of map is determined by the number of input splits. What about the number of reduce? If there is a method that we can determine the reduce intuitively?
I am doing map reduce in Pig.

Answer (score 1):

Ideal reducers should be the optimal value that gets them closest to:

A multiple of the block size
A task time between 5 and 15 minutes
Creates the fewest files possible
Reference : http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces

Answer (score 0):

From the data point of view, the number of reducers is equal to the number of unique keys in your map output.